# Reduce javascript list of lists to a dictionary of lists

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Similar to [List of Lists to Dictionary of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686087/list-of-lists-to-dictionary-of-lists)

Would like to reduce a list of lists to a dictionary of lists
For example

```
list_list = [['example', 55], ['example', 66] , ['example2', 44]]
```

would become

```
dict = {'example': [55,66], 'example2': [44]}
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to have do some handson, thats why answering this.

`Array.reduce` and array destructuring will help you.

Please see the code comment for logic

```js
const list_list = [['example', 55], ['example', 66] , ['example2', 44]];
//Destructuring the current value in the reduce function into [key, value]
const dict = list_list.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  // If a node with the current key exist in the accumulator, merge the value of that node with current value
  // If node with current key doesnot exist, create a new node with that key and value as an array with current value being the element
  acc[key] = acc[key] ? [...acc[key], value] : [value];
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here comes another variant of how the reducer function could be implemented. It tries to be more readable and also features a comment for each of the 3 steps which have to be taken with every reduce cycle.

Documentation links:

- [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring)
- [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [`??=` The logical nullish assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

```js
const list_list = [['example', 55], ['example', 66] , ['example2', 44]];

console.log(
  list_list

  //.reduce((result, item) => {
  //  // array destructuring of the currently processed array item.
  //  const [key, value] = item;

    // array destructuring within the reducer function's head.
    .reduce((result, [key, value]) => {

      // create and/or access the property list
      // identified by the array item's `key`.
      const groupList = (result[key] ??= []);

      // push the array item's `value`
      // into the above accessed list.
      groupList.push(value);

      // return the mutated `result` ... (the
      // stepwise aggregated final return value).
      return result;

    }, {}) // pass the final result's initial state as 2nd argument.
)
```

Comment: @peewee6765 ... Regarding the above approach are there any questions left?